# $G$ cyclic group of order $24$, and $H=\langle x^6\rangle$, find the order of each element of $G/H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

As the title says I have:
$G$ cyclic group of order 24, and $H= \langle x^6 \rangle$ , we also know that $x$ is a generator of $G$ so, $\langle x \rangle = G$

i have to find the order of each element of the quotient group $G/H$

and say how many generators have $G/H$

Comment: I'm the \langle \rangle fairy, here to let you know that $\langle, \rangle$ plays nicer with TeX than <, > does :)

Comment: Is $H$ generated by $x^6$ for some particular $x$ you forgot to define or $H$ is generated by all elements of $G$ that are of the form $x^6$?

Comment: I think she forgot to mention that $x$ is a generator of $G.$

Comment: i think that $G=\{e,x,x^2,x^3,...,x^6,...,x^(23) \}$ since $G$ is a cyclic group.

Comment: @Zigisfredo it's not automatic, you need to mention that. If $x$ is an arbitrary element of $G$ then its order could be less than $24.$

Comment: Does 'how many generators' mean 'the smallest possible cardinality of a set of generators' or 'the number of elements that individually generate $G/H$'?

Comment: the number of elements that individually generate $G/H$.

Comment: Ah, so the question already foreshadows our proof that $G/H$ will be cyclic. I will adapt my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(answer adapted to some of the comments)*

The order of $H$ is the order of its generator $x^6,$ i.e., 4. Therefore the order of $G/H$ is 6: there are 6 different cosets of the form $x^iH.$

We can choose the first powers of $x$ as representatives of these cosets:

$$G/H=\left\{H,xH,x^2H,x^3H,x^4H,x^5H\right\}$$

The order of an individual coset $x^iH$ is the smallest nonzero natural number $n$ such that $i.n$ is a multiple of 6.

Now at least one of the elements of $G/H$ turns out to have its order equal to the order of $G/H$ itself, implying that $G/H$ is cyclic.

A cyclic group is generated by an individual element $g$ iff the order of that element is the order of the group.

Comment: i think that i found the order of $H$, since $H=\langle x^6 \rangle=\{e,x^6,x^12,x^18\}$ so the order of $H=4$ therefore the order of $G/H$ is 4. But after that i'm confused about how to get for each element the order.

Comment: No, the order of $G/H$ is determined by Lagrange's theorem and it's different from 4.

Comment: oh, so i have, $o(G/H)=o(G)/o(H)=24/4=6$.

Comment: Yep, you're on your way! Now propose representatives of the 6 cosets of $H.$

Comment: Should i take $x^p$ with $p$ a prime number so i could get the order easier?

Comment: Let's not go looking to far. For the moment, consider *any* element $g=x^i$ of $G$ and its coset $x^iH.$ The order of that coset is, by definition, the smallest nonzero natural number $n$ such that $(x^iH)^n=H,$ i.e., such that $x^{i.n}\in H.$ Can you find a way to express this as a condition on the integer $i$?

Comment: if i have that $x^{i.n}\in H$ therefor ${i.n}$ is a multiple of 6, so $i$ is a multiple of 6?

Comment: Correct that $x^{i.n}\in H$ iff $i.n$ is a multiple of 6. That does not mean that $i$ is a multiple of 6, only that $n$ is the smallest number such that $i.n$ becomes one. Now find the smallest such $n$ for individual values of $i=0,1,2,3,\ldots$

Comment: The smallest $n$ such that ${i.n}$ become one for the individual values of $i$ is $n=2$?, since $i=12$ implies that $(12)(2)=24=0$

Comment: What I meant was that you should find the smallest $n$ such that $0.n$ is a multiple of 6, then the (possibly different) smallest $n$ such that $1.n$ is a multiple of 6, then the (possibly yet different) smallest $n$ such that $2.n$ is a multiple of 6, and so on. Each time you will be computing the order of an element of $G/H.$

Comment: ok, so i compute some of those $n$ and i get;
if $i$ is a prime i get $n=6$
if $i$ is a multiple of 2 i get $n=3$
if $i$ is a multiple of 3 get $n=2$

Comment: also, if $i$ is a multiple of 6 get $n=1$ and when $i=0$ $n=0$?

Comment: That's perfect, except for the remark about $i=0$: we are looking for nonzero natural numbers $n$ only, so the smallest is $n=1$ and therefore $i=0$ is no exception to the rule you found about multiples of 6.

Comment: Now propose an *easy* choice of 6 elements of $G$ that represent distinct cosets of $H.$

Comment: so now i just need for example with, $x^6x^i, x^6 \in H, x^i \in G$... here i could take $i=1$ so i get $x^7$ so i just saw that it have order 6. and so on with the rest?

Comment: The choice of six different representatives becomes even easier if you do not multiply $x^i$ by $x^6$ but by $e=x^0.$ Remember that you need 6 different ones, because the assignment wants you to compute the order of *each* element of $G/H$ (= each distinct coset of $H$).

Comment: ok, if i use $e=x^0$. I get for $o(x^6)=4,o(x^{12})=2,o(x^{18})=4$

Comment: Those are the orders of the elements in the original group $G.$ What you need is the order of the coset of any given element in the factor group $G/H$  (the number $n$ we talked about, and which you effectively found for several cases of $i$). What I am asking you is to propose six choices of $i$ such that the six $x^i$ lie in different cosets of $H,$ i.e., such that $x^{i_1}.(x^{i_2})^{-1}$ is not in $H.$

Comment: mmh,i think i understand the idea but i have that the quotient group their cosets are the cases of $i$.. but i really don't  get how to chose the six representatives

Comment: OK then I am giving them to you: see updated answer.